# GDI+ DrawString doesnt draw on PDF and PNG Format

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, watermark

I want to draw water mark on some documents like JPG, DOCX, PNG and PDF when printing. for this purpose, I Hook [EndPage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-endpage) function and use GDI+ `DrawString` to Draw Some Text. My code works well for `Docx` and `JPG` but the when I print `PDF` or `PNG` the water mark is not drawn. Any body know why this happened?
this my code:

*I get water mark info trough RPC I check RPC the info received correctly in all formats*

````
    int EndPageHook::hookFunction(HDC hdc)
{


    //Intialize GdiplusStartupInput and Graphics
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    Graphics graphic_Obj(hdc);

    //Get Watermark Information Throught RPC
    WatermarkParameters = WaterMarkRPCClient::GetWaterMarkInfo(status, printInfo);
    
    //Get Watermark Information and set in local variables
    string s = std::to_string(WatermarkParameters.transparency);
    s = std::to_string(WatermarkParameters.positions);
    s = std::to_string(WatermarkParameters.font);

    //Concatenation Text + User + Ip + Date 
    wcsncat_s(finalsenetce, WatermarkParameters._text, 512);

    if (WatermarkParameters.Has_UserName)
    {
        wcsncat_s(finalsenetce, WatermarkParameters._username, 256);
    }
    if (WatermarkParameters.Has_Client)
    {
        wcsncat_s(finalsenetce, WatermarkParameters._client, 256);
    }
    if (WatermarkParameters.Has_Date)
    {
        wcsncat_s(finalsenetce, WatermarkParameters._date, 256);
    }
    {
    
        //Set watermark position
        StringAlignment WMLocation{};
        StringFormat stringFormat;
        switch (WatermarkParameters.positions)
        {
        case 1:
            stringFormat.SetAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentNear);
            stringFormat.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentNear);
            break;
        case 2:
            stringFormat.SetAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentCenter);
            stringFormat.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentCenter);
            break;
        case 3:
            stringFormat.SetAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentFar);
            stringFormat.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentFar);
            break;
        default:
            stringFormat.SetAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentCenter);
            stringFormat.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentCenter);
            break;
        }


        
        // Claculate Page Size
        double WidthsPixels = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES); 
        double   HeightsPixels = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES);
        double WidthsPixelsPerInch = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);
        double   HeightsPixelsPeInch = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);
        ////----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

        Gdiplus::FontFamily nameFontFamily(L"Arial");
        Gdiplus::Font         font(&nameFontFamily, WatermarkParameters.font, Gdiplus::FontStyleBold, Gdiplus::UnitPoint);
        Gdiplus::RectF        rectF(0, 0, 20, 20);
        Gdiplus::SolidBrush   solidBrush(Gdiplus::Color(WatermarkParameters.transparency, 250, 0, 250));

        rectF.Width = (HeightsPixels / HeightsPixelsPeInch)* Screendpi;
        rectF.Height = (WidthsPixels / WidthsPixelsPerInch)* Screendpi;
        


        graphic_Obj.DrawString(finalsenetce, -1, &font, rectF, &stringFormat, &solidBrush);
    }
    GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken); 

    return getOriginalFunction()(hdc);```
}
````

Comment: I change `return  getOriginalFunction()(hdc);` to `return 1;` and PNG format fixed, but the PDF still not working.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could try to use `PdfGraphics.DrawString` instead of `Graphics::DrawString`.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I try to use  `PdfGraphics`  but base on this [link](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.Pdf.PdfGraphics) the `PdfGraphics` class is usable in `C#` and `VB.NET`. I use `C++` so I can't Use this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the solution...
First I must `return 1;` instead of `return getOriginalFunction()(hdc);`.
Second I must add Scope `{` before `Graphics graphic_Obj(hdc);` and close it
after `GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken);` here is the correct code

```
    int EndPageHook::hookFunction(HDC hdc)
{
    //Intialize GdiplusStartupInput and Graphics
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    {
        Graphics graphic_Obj(hdc);

        //Get Watermark Information Throught RPC
        WatermarkParameters = WaterMarkRPCClient::GetWaterMarkInfo(status, printInfo);



        //Get Watermark Information and set in local variables
        string s = std::to_string(WatermarkParameters.transparency);
        s = std::to_string(WatermarkParameters.positions);
        s = std::to_string(WatermarkParameters.font);

        //Concatenation Text + User + Ip + Date 
        wcsncat_s(finalsenetce, WatermarkParameters._text, 512);

        if (WatermarkParameters.Has_UserName)
        {
            wcsncat_s(finalsenetce, WatermarkParameters._username, 256);
        }
        if (WatermarkParameters.Has_Client)
        {
            wcsncat_s(finalsenetce, WatermarkParameters._client, 256);
        }
        if (WatermarkParameters.Has_Date)
        {
            wcsncat_s(finalsenetce, WatermarkParameters._date, 256);
        }


        //Set watermark position
        StringAlignment WMLocation{};
        StringFormat stringFormat;
        switch (WatermarkParameters.positions)
        {
        case 1:
            stringFormat.SetAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentNear);
            stringFormat.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentNear);
            break;
        case 2:
            stringFormat.SetAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentCenter);
            stringFormat.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentCenter);
            break;
        case 3:
            stringFormat.SetAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentFar);
            stringFormat.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentFar);
            break;
        default:
            stringFormat.SetAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentCenter);
            stringFormat.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignment::StringAlignmentCenter);
            break;
        }



        // Claculate Page Size
        double WidthsPixels = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES); // Get Device WIDTH
        double   HeightsPixels = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES);//Get Device HEIGHT
        double WidthsPixelsPerInch = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);// Get Document  Pixel Per Inch in WIDTH of Screen
        double   HeightsPixelsPeInch = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);// Get Document Pixel Per Inch in HEIGHT of Screen
        ////----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

        Gdiplus::FontFamily nameFontFamily(L"Arial");
        Gdiplus::Font         font(&nameFontFamily, WatermarkParameters.font, Gdiplus::FontStyleBold, Gdiplus::UnitPoint);
        Gdiplus::RectF        rectF(0, 0, 200, 200);
        Gdiplus::SolidBrush   solidBrush(Gdiplus::Color(WatermarkParameters.transparency, 250, 0, 250));


        rectF.Width = (HeightsPixels / HeightsPixelsPeInch)* Screendpi;
        rectF.Height = (WidthsPixels / WidthsPixelsPerInch)* Screendpi;

        graphic_Obj.DrawString(finalsenetce, -1, &font, rectF, &stringFormat, &solidBrush);
    }
    GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken);

    return 1;
}
```